# How to mock a function in multiple modules

Tags: python, mocking

I am currently working on extending a third-party code base. This code base unfortunately tightly couples its `get_args` with every other function. `get_args` is basically just a getter for a global object `_ARGS`. Now, I'd like to modify the args for a single function call without actually modifying the global object itself.

To this end, I used `unittest.mock.patch` to patch the `get_args` function, and while it succeeds in patching it in my target function `f`, it does not translate to functions called by `f` if they are in other modules. The reason is, of course, that I only patch `get_args` in the module with the called function `f`.

Is it possible to mock *every* subsequent call to `get_args` within my `with` block?

My current approach might not be the best one to tackle this problem, so I'm also open to alternative solutions to this problem.

Minimum reproducible example:

My code `main.py`:

```
from argparse import Namespace
import unittest.mock

from mod0 import get_args
from mod1 import f1


def new_get_args():
    return Namespace(**{
        **get_args().__dict__,
        'a': 'a',
    })


def main():
    with unittest.mock.patch('mod1.get_args', new=new_get_args):
        f1()

main()
```

Module `mod0`:

```
from argparse import Namespace

_ARGS = None


def get_args():
    global _ARGS
    if _ARGS is None:
        _ARGS = Namespace(a=1, b=2)
    return _ARGS
```

Module `mod1`:

```
from mod0 import get_args
from mod2 import f2


def f1():
    args = get_args()
    args.c = 3
    print(f"[f1] Args: {args}")
    f2()
```

Module `mod2`:

```
from mod0 import get_args


def f2():
    args = get_args()
    print(f"[f2] Args: {args}")
```

Result:

```
[f1] Args: Namespace(a='a', b=2, c=3)
[f2] Args: Namespace(a=1, b=2)
```

What I need:

```
[f1] Args: Namespace(a='a', b=2, c=3)
[f2] Args: Namespace(a='a', b=2, c=3)
```